# "Unable to start debugging. The application uses a version of Silverlight that isn't supported by this debugger."

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, debugging

Im using VS 2010 to make silverlight application using silverlight 4.0
Debugger and everything worked fine until 3 days ago when this message sudenly showed up. It shows every time I try to run my silverlight application. I tried reinstalling siverlight 4 sdk it didn't helped.
What can I do? Internets search gives nothing.
(btw I tried installing VS2010 SP1 after message start showing, it also didnt helped)

Comment: What OS are you using, and what "bitness" is it?

Comment: This doesn't sound like the case, but this happened to me after installing new minor version of SL runtime. It always must be **developer** runtime that you will install - [newest for now](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2011/02/14/silverlight-february-2011-update-gdr3.aspx)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever its XP 32 bits

Answer (score 1):

I have same problems when trying to debug SL5 app. SL 5 Dev Runtime installation fixed the problem. Checkout http://www.silverlight.net/downloads for lastest downloadable version.
In your case, you need to install additional Silverlight **4** Developer Runtime,
 you can find it here:

- [SL 4 Dev Runtime](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/2/C/22CABA89-3580-4611-8E0D-56749D2120DF/runtime/Silverlight_Developer.exe)
- [SL 3 Dev Runtime](http://go2.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=150228)